# URL is not showing all files select by user?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on phonegap where I need to upload the file and add all file name into the params, like:

http://www.example.com/uplaod.html?file=file1,file2,file3

For that I'm trying this:

```
function new_page()
{
  var file3=document.getElementById('my_file');
  var data_file=document.getElementById('file_handle').innerHTML;
  if(file3!=null)
  {
    var file=document.getElementById('my_file').innerHTML;
    file+=data_file;
    window.location.href='job_posting.html?file='+file;
  }
  else
  {
    window.location.href='job_posting.html';
  }
}
```

When I upload multiple file then it creating link with only 1st file which I selected:

Like:

http://www.example.com/upload.html?file=file

*but it should be*

http://www.example.com/uplaod.html?file=file1,file2,file3

Comment: What web server do you use ? Is it apache ?

Comment: @iamsleepy is there server real matter ??

Comment: @simmant, I stumbled upon something similar to this because of incorrect rewrite. Might be related, or might be not.

Comment: i think sevre not matter with this case only what need to change is the function let suppose if it have multi-upload on phonegap they must use span so they need to add from that span @iamsleepy right ?

Comment: can you show the html

Comment: Here is my HTML Code: http://pastebin.com/kWAL4n9W

Comment: I think you might be right @simmant. Because no html was shown, I made wild assumptions.

Comment: I can't find element with id `my_file` in your code.

Comment: i think you should have to try with file_handle what you say @iamsleepy

Comment: <span data-ng-switch-default id="my_file">{{filelist.name}}</span>

Comment: If you mean your form input with name `files[]`. You can access it with `document.getElementByName('files[]');` and loop to create the files string. Then `window.location.href` it.

Answer (score 0):

I would collect the additional files as an array and parse on the url as a JSON string.

Then use php json_decode